# Ubuntu WSL issue : error lunching Spyder IDE

Tags: ubuntu, spyder, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After lunching Spyder IDE on UBUNTU there is this error message coming up :

```
QStandardPaths: wrong permissions on runtime directory    /run/user/1000/, 0755 instead of 0700 
MESA: error: ZINK: failed to load libvulkan.so.1 
glx: failed to create drisw screen
failed to load driver: zink 
fromIccProfile: failed minimal tag size sanity
```

Spyder is working but with an interface problem : there is an offset between the mouse and the pointing zone.
Doing a full screen on/off fixed it but it still is problematic.

Uninstalling and re-installing Spyder multiple times didn't do anything (it's even worse...)

Comment: Found the solution thanks to that spage : https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/1148